# Prove that the sequence generated by {$x_k$} with arbitrary $x_0$ converges to the root of $f(x) = 0$

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

Let $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ be continuous in $(− ∞, ∞)$ and $M ≥ f'(x) ≥ m > 0$ for all $x ∈
(− ∞, ∞)$. Prove that the sequence ${x_k}$ generated by
$x_{k +1} = x_k − λf(x_k)$, k = 0, 1, 2, ...
with arbitrary $x_0$ converges to the root of $f(x) = 0$ for any choice of $λ$ in the interval
$0 < λ < \frac{2}{M}$.

I thought of using methods from the order of convergence and Newton methods but I am clueless as to how I can approach this proof. Any suggestions and/ or examples will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: This problem looks similar to finding the stability region of the forward Euler scheme.

Comment: @Mattos I am not familiar with that topic as I am only starting to study numerical analysis. Assuming I have knowledge up to and inclusive that of Fixed point method, Newton Raphson's method, and fixed point iteration.

Comment: $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ bounded above by $M$ $\forall x$ means $f$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $M$. You then essentially want to follow the proof given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration#Properties) using your sequence.

Comment: Note: depending how you interpret the question, you might also have to prove that f only has one root. But with the intermediate value theorem, that is a formality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just a Hint**

Let $g(x)=x-\lambda f(x)$

$0<m\leq f'(x) \leq M \implies$

$0<m\leq \frac{1-g'(x)}{\lambda}\leq M$

$\implies \lambda m-1\leq -g'(x)\leq \lambda M-1$

the sequence converges if

$|g'(x)|<K<1 \implies \lambda M-1<1 \implies \lambda<\frac{2}{M}$.

Comment: Ah this clears things up quite a bit! So with this initial argument you proposed followed by the proof @Mattos suggested above in the comments, will that suffice to show the convergence for the sequence as well as the justification for arbitrary $λ$?